# Link over image hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I have 2 images that are changing when I hover on the first one.

On the second one, I have some text because I want a link there.
My problem is now that I want the hover image to remain when I hover over the link.

Here is my code:

```css
 #blur {
  border: 1px solid #bebfc1;
  position:relative;
  height:450px;
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
  -webkit-transition: border 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: border 1s ease-in-out;
}

#blur img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#blur:hover {
  z-index:2;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#blur img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}

#blur .text {
  position:absolute;
  color:#bebfc1;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  font-family:"Segoe UI Light";
  font-size:13px;
}

#blur:hover .text {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="blur">
  <img class="bottom" src="http://s28.postimg.org/do5izc4gd/image.png" />
  <img class="top" src="http://s28.postimg.org/a5tj2y3kd/image.png" />
  <p class="text" style="bottom:6px; left:180px;"><a href="#">link</a></p>
</div>
```

When I hover over the link I want the red image to remain the same.
How can this be done?
Thanks !!!

DEMO here http://jsfiddle.net/VYR9q/

Comment: Your jsfiddle link dose nit have any image

Comment: yes it does, one it's full red one full blue

Comment: I say that your jsfiddle file is incorrect,change it to review your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it in the fiddle line you provided :)

Here you are what I fixed:

```
 #blur:hover .top {
     opacity:0;
 }
```

Instead of:

```
#blur img.top:hover {
    opacity:0;

}
```

Edit from: @biziclop:
You can make it:

```
#blur:hover img.top
```

Comment: @Robo374 You are welcome.
Please if this helped you, make this answer the correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you should simply move `:hover` from the `img` to the common parent `#blur`

```
#blur img.top:hover {
```

to

```
#blur:hover img.top {
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/VYR9q/2/

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to :

```
#blur:hover img.top {
   //your css
}
```